# xpath expression to get only text content of node for dynamic content

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm trying to catch content of `<div class="num">` without  child element from the below HTML code:

```
<div class="num">
   <del>14,490</del>
   13,490
</div>
```

So I'm expecting `13,490` as result.

I use the following xpath expression for that:

```
//div[@class="num"]/node()[not(self::del)]
```

which works fine for this example, but the problem is that the content of the div may vary and sometimes it doesn't contain the  child element.

I'm using Python and can handle this on coding level but I'm curious whether this can be done by xpath only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just get the `text()`:

```
//div[@class="num"]/text()
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '//div[@class="num"]/node()[not(self::del)]'
13,490
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '//div[@class="num"]/text()'
13,490
```

This would also work if there is no `del` tag:

```
<div class="num">
   13,490
</div>
```

Comment: You don't really need `child::`.

Comment: Oops, you are right, guys, overcomplicated it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all! Just wanted to answer my own post with the same solution. Just finished testing it out and it works fine. Thanks for thaking the time.